# NullPointerException in closing jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

While I am trying to close the JDBC it is throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
public void getDBConnection() throws SQLException {
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root123");
}

public void closeDB() throws SQLException {
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: add if(conn != null) check in closeDB().

Comment: How on earth do you format your code? Do you just insert random whitespace for fun? Also the correct way to register a driver is `Class.forName("my.driver.Class")`, it is the driver's responsibility to register itself at static init.

Comment: Your `conn` object is `null` . What do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assure before close connection that `conn` instance initialized or not. so once need to call `getDBConnection`method, because `conn` object initialize in it. then you can call `closeDB`. Add check like `if(conn != null)` to be safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-with-resource statement of Java 7. It is `AutoCloseable` by default. It is safe and easy. For example,

```
 try(Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(..)){

 }
```